# ATI HyperMemory - Accessible on 1GB of total HyperMemory 4,5GB

Tags: amd-radeon

I have laptop with Radeon graphic chip and support of HyperMemory, however, I have total 4GB on graphics from HyperMemory, but I have available only 1Gb, any solutions to get more vram?

Comment: How much system RAM do you have, & is your OS 32 or 64-bit? Bear in mind [HyperMemory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperMemory) was a low-end solution, from over a decade ago & on 32-bit OS 1GB is probably as much as you can afford.

Comment: I have 64bit system with 8gb ram